# Neo4j- APOC trigger fires without any reason

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following two triggers named 'loadEnrollments' and 'loadDeenrollments'.

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('loadEnrollments',
"UNWIND apoc.trigger.nodesByLabel($assignedLabels, 'Enrollment') AS node
 MERGE (p1:SPerson { name: node.name, cell: node.cell, created_at: node.created_at})
 WITH p1, node
 MATCH (n:SPerson)
 WITH node, COUNT(n) as size
 CALL apoc.do.when(
 size>3,
 '
 MATCH(p1:SPerson),(c:Course)
 WHERE p1.name=node.name AND c.name=\"Paradigm Shifting 101\"
 CREATE (p1)-[:Waitlist]->(c)
 SET p1.status=2
 WITH node
 RETURN NULL',
 '
 MATCH(p1:SPerson),(c:Course)
 WHERE p1.name=node.name AND c.name=\"Paradigm Shifting 101\"
 CREATE (p1)-[:Enrolled]->(c)
 SET p1.status=1
 WITH node
 RETURN NULL', {node:node}) YIELD value
 DETACH DELETE node",

 { phase: 'after' })



CALL apoc.trigger.add('loadDeenrollments',
"
UNWIND apoc.trigger.nodesByLabel($assignedLabels, 'Deenrollment') AS node
 MATCH (p1:SPerson {name: node.name, cell: node.cell})
 MATCH (c:Course {name: 'Paradigm Shifting 101'})
 CREATE (p1)-[:Deenrolled]->(c)
   SET p1.status=3
 WITH p1, node,c
 MATCH (p1:SPerson {name: node.name, cell: node.cell})-[r:Enrolled]->(c)
 DELETE r
 DETACH DELETE node
 WITH p1,c
 MATCH (p1)-[r:Enrolled]->(c)
 WITH COUNT(r) as k
 CALL apoc.do.when(
 k<3,     '
  MATCH (p1:SPerson)-[:Waitlist]->(c:Course)
  WITH min(p1.created_at) AS min
  MATCH (p1:SPerson),(c:Course)
  WHERE p1.created_at = min
  CREATE (p1)-[:Random]->(c)
  RETURN p1,c',
 '
 MATCH (n:SPerson) RETURN n
 ',{k:k}
 ) YIELD value
 RETURN NULL",

 { phase: 'after' })
```

When I load both of them and create a 'Enrollment' nodes by the following commands. The 'loadenrollment' trigger works as desired and create SPerson nodes for cat1,cat2 and cat3 and creates an 'enrolled' relationship with the 'course' node.

```
CREATE (:Enrollment { name: "cat1", cell: "123", created_at: TIMESTAMP()});
CREATE (:Enrollment { name: "cat2", cell: "123", created_at: TIMESTAMP()});
CREATE (:Enrollment { name: "cat3", cell: "123", created_at: TIMESTAMP()});
```

The Problem occurs when I create the 4th node

```
CREATE (:Enrollment { name: "cat4", cell: "123", created_at: TIMESTAMP()});
```

Ideally, it should create a SPerson node for cat4 and add a 'waitlist' relationship with the 'course' node.
But for some reason when I create that node it adds the 'waitlist' relationship but also adds the 'Random' relationship that I defined in the second trigger('loadDeenrollments'). This should never happen as this trigger would only trigger when I create a 'Deenrollment' node but for some reason it is executing that trigger.

Also, I tried adding just the 'loadEnrollments' trigger and it works as desired(obviously, as there is no 'loadDeenrollments' trigger) i.e. creating the four 'SPerson' nodes and with three nodes having 'enrolled' relationship and one having 'waitlist' relationship.

I don't know whats's wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which Neo4j version ? Are there any other triggers enabled at the moment? You can see all triggers with `call apoc.trigger.list`

Comment: Neo4j v4.1.0,

call apoc.trigger.list, gives me both 'loadEnrollments' and 'loadDeenrollments' are  on (installed) and this is as desired and there are no other triggers beside these. Just to elaborate further, My question is the 'loadDeenrollments' should never even fire when I am creating 'Enrollment nodes', It should only fire when I am creating a 'Deenrollment' node (like this. CREATE (:Deenrollment { name: "cat1", cell: "123"});)